# Spring data jpa throws TransientObjectException on a very specific scenario

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Using spring-boot (2.1.8.RELEASE), I have a test looking like this:

```
    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void myTest() {
        Company updatedCompany = companyRepository.save(company);

        em.detach(updatedCompany);

        // (1)
        companyRepository.getOne(updatedCompany.getId());

        // (2)
        companyRepository.save(updatedCompany);
    }
```

where:

- `company` is initialized as a domain entity.
- `em` is an `EntityManager`.
- `companyRepository` extends `JpaRepository<Company, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Company>`.

This throws a `TransientObjectException` on line `(2)`.

However, replacing line `(1)` with `companyRepository.findById(updatedCompany.getId()).get()` makes everything run without an exception.

This is not an actual test, but a reproduced problem from my code that I'm trying to understand.

Some more versions:

- spring-data-jpa: 2.1.10.RELEASE
- hibernate-core: 5.3.11.Final
- hibernate-entitymanager: 5.3.11.Final

Comment: This is not a solution but you don't need `@Transactional` on test class

Comment: As I said, this is a reproduction, not an actual test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research, appears to be caused by: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-13590.

Upgrading hibernate-core to 5.3.12.Final solves the problem.